# apache's httpd.conf DocumentRoot -> removable media

Tags: apache

I'm setting up a custom portable version of Apache on Windows. A XAMPP built from scratch.
So it is portable. When httpd is started, one of the VirtualHost folders may not be available at that moment (removable device)

```
<VirtualHost  127.0.0.1:8081>
  ServerName  myserver
  DocumentRoot "F:/PROJECT1"
</VirtualHost>
```

So **httpd** won't start because that DocumentRoot is missing:

```
DocumentRoot must be a directory
```

Is there a way to ignore the missing directory (which will be later available)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same situation and I wrote own bat file to run server (Apache). I didn`t found better solution.

This code defines some variable - Project1.

StartServer.bat

```
set params=
if exist some_path\project1 (
    set params=%params%" -D Project1"
)
"apache_path/bin/httpd.exe%params%"
```

And when you describes you virtual hosts you can put some logic depends on this variable:

```
<IfDefine Project1>
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081>
        ...
    </VirtualHost>
</IfDefine>
```